# CQ5: Controlling a dialog from a design_dialog

Tags: javascript, aem

Is it possible to almost dynamically generate a dialog based on properties set on the design_dialog in cq5/aem? Somewhere along the lines of the column container but rather than having two components (one for column container and one for the child) the same component will draw its options based on what was selected on the design_dialog.

Comment: What is your use case for that? Settings in the design dialogs are globally applied for all components in comparison to settings in normal dialogs which are component's node related. So this means that you can alter the behaviour of all components of this type with a single setting in a design dialog (for example if your components displays pages, you can set the limit to 10 for all components)

Comment: @d33t, for example lets assume I have 3 components, each component will display different options based on settings from the design_dialog. For example on the design_dialog you can specify component 1 display 1 option, component 2 display 5 options, component 3 display 10 options. If you want to change those numbers you can always go back to the design_dialog and say you can change component 3 to have 50 options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your answer to my comment above, I can assume that you are trying to achieve something that is far a way from the standards in CQ and you are not really talking about generation of dialogs in components. Design dialogs are template specific and used to store global settings and affect this way the component's behaviour. If you want to provide something such as dynamic dialogs feature, than you can implement for example some servlet filter which would be responsible for altering of the dialog definitions. From my experience, I can tell you that this would be case that you probably never have and there is mostly much ellegant solution for the requirements you have. I don't thing that I can provide you with fully quallified answer from the description you gave so far. Please post your full requierement if you expect such an answer.

Comment: I will accept this answer, however I need to re-think my thought process on what I am trying to do. I have the feeling that my approach may be acceptable :).